# Table filter not working with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm creating table filter for my project. With input fields it works perfectly, but I can't manage to work properly select2 filter, it just don't work.. Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.filterable .filters input, select').keyup(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == '9') return;
    var $input = $(this),
      inputContent = $input.val().toLowerCase(),
      $panel = $input.parents('.filterable'),
      column = $panel.find('.filters th').index($input.parents('th')),
      $table = $panel.find('.table'),
      $rows = $table.find('tbody tr');

    var $filteredRows = $rows.filter(function() {
      var value = $(this).find('td').eq(column).text().toLowerCase();
      return value.indexOf(inputContent) === -1;
    });

    $table.find('tbody .no-result').remove();
    $rows.show();
    $filteredRows.hide();

    if ($filteredRows.length === $rows.length) {
      $table.find('tbody').prepend($('<tr class="no-result text-center"><td colspan="' + $table.find('.filters th').length + '">Deja, bet rezultatų nepavyko rasti</td></tr>'));
    }
  });
});

$("#street").select2({
  minimumInputLength: 3
});
```

And here is my JsFiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/5202jsax/9/

Appreciate for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/5202jsax/10/)**.

The `keyup` event will not work for the list `select`, you've just to add the `change` event also to deal with the select elements, like :

```
$('.filterable .filters input, select').on('input change', function(e) {
    //Your logic HERE
});
```

**NOTE :** I'm using the `input` event in this example since it's more efficient when dealing with the user inputs.